# conexion a java con mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

en realidad no  tan buenos JAJA, tengo un problema con la conexion de java a mysql ya importe la libreria el jar aun asi hice la conexion y me dice que la conexion no esta establecida.

les muestro el codigo de la conexion

```
package modelo.dao;
    import java.sql.*;


public class conexion  {

    static String bd = "merca_ruta";
    static String login = "root";
    static String password ="";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:/" + bd;


    Connection conn = null;



 public conexion (){
     try {
         // cargar nuestro driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         conn=DriverManager.getConnection("url, login, password");

         if (conn != null) {
             System.out.println("Conenecting database [" + conn + "] OK");
         }
     } catch (SQLException e) 
     {
         System.out.println("Exepcion conexion: " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
         System.out.println("Excepcion driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
     }  

public Connection getConnection() {
    return conn;
}

public void disconnet(){
    System.out.println("closing database: ["+ conn + "] OK");
    if (conn !=null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
       }
    }
}
```

espero me puedan ayudar les agradeceria gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu url esta mal `jdbc:mysql://localhost:/` quitale los segundos dos puntos `jdbc:mysql://localhost/` y tambien aqui estas mal:

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("url, login, password");
```

debe ser `conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);`

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede ayudar a resolver tu problema.

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/nombre_bd",
                "root", "dbpass");
        return con;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Database.getConnection() Error -->" + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public static void close(Connection con) {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace el código que pones? ¿cómo resuelve el problema de la pregunta? ¿dónde debería ir en el código de la pregunta?